# What is the parametric equations for the following closed curves?

Tags: plane-curves, parametric

1. First case

   [image]
2. Second case

   [image]

For the sake of simplicity, let the circle of radius $R$ be at the origin, the rectangle width and height be $w$ and $h$, respectively.

Comment: It seems like the program for that animation would have the exact behavior of the shapes involved, and thus the curve being created.

Comment: The second one is four quarter-circles joined by straight segments of lengths equal to the height and width of the rectangle.